# Refference error: Set variable is not defined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a problem here. I couldn't find any useful information, so I'm posting here.

My code:

```
function dateVerifier (submitButton, dateElement) {
    this.submitButton = $(submitButton);
    this.dateElement = $(dateElement);
    var self = this;

    this.validateDateBeforeToday = function() {
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var inputDate = new Date(self.dateElement.val());
    return inputDate.getTime() < todaysDate.getTime();
}
    this.validateDateFormat = function() {
    var dateFormat = self.dateElement.val();
      return !dateFormat;
}
```

My code somehow doesn't read this line:

```
var dateFormat = self.dateElement.val();
```

It doesn't print any error to the console, but I checked it by entering the variable name inside of the console and it says that it's undefined. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for any help

Comment: where do you call your functions?

Comment: Are you sure `dateElement` point to a valid input element?

Comment: @Fanyo SILIADIN It's inside of my html file, but im just calling new instance of dateVerifier and it's enough, because all the information are in the constructor

Comment: @Sirko Somehow the same element is caught in the `inputDate` variable and it's printing the result of '`invalidDate`'

Comment: A quick fiddle works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3717cx6h/